# text-align right in small width div

Tags: css, text-align

I'm trying to align text to the right in a small area.  It becomes left align when the container is small.  Is there anyway to force it right align?

```
div 
{ float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
text-align: right;
border: thin solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a362zr54/

Comment: For future uses to know, please accept an answer, if any, that best solve your question.

Answer (score 5):

If you add `direction: rtl;` it will do that

```css
div { 
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  border: thin solid black;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div>
1testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest2
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `direction: rtl;`, but this might mess up your text.

If your content has a fixed size like in your example. You can also use `position:absolute;right:0;` like this:

```css
.container { float: right;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: thin solid black;
position:relative;
}
.content {
  text-align: right;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="content">
testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `direction: rtl;` to the container.

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/a362zr54/1/